# Using type casts to have different objects in a single vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a paymentList vector which has Cash, Cheque and Credit objects (which are derived classes of Payment) inside of the vector.

I declare the vector like this:

```
typedef std::vector<Payment*> ListOfPayments;
```

I add payments like this:

```
std::cout << "How would you like to pay?" << std::endl;
std::cout << "1. Cash"  <<std::endl;
std::cout << "2. Credit"<<std::endl;
std::cout << "3. Cheque"<<std::endl;
std::cin >> choice;

while(choice < 1 || choice > 3)
{
  std::cout<<"Please enter a correct number from 1 to 3"<<std::endl;
  std::cin >> choice;
}
if(choice == 1)
{
  paymentList->push_back(addCash(paymentId,orderId));
}
else if(choice == 2)
{
  paymentList->push_back(addCredit(paymentId,orderId));
}
else
{
  paymentList->push_back(addCheque(paymentId,orderId));
}
```

I now want to save this vector to a file. I have started a save function but I'm unsure where to go from here:

```
void savePayment(ListOfPayments *paymentList)
{
    int method;
    Cheque * pCheque = dynamic_cast<Cheque *>(paymentList->at(paymentList->size()-1));
    Cash * pCash = dynamic_cast<Cash *>(paymentList->at(paymentList->size()-1));
    Credit * pCredit = dynamic_cast<Credit *>(paymentList->at(paymentList->size()-1));
    std::ofstream* save = new std::ofstream(); // creates a pointer to a new ofstream
    save->open("Payments.txt"); //opens a text file called payments.
    if (!save->is_open())
    {
        std::cout<<"The file is not open.";
    }
    else
    {
        *save << paymentList->size() << "\n";
        ListOfPayments::iterator iter = paymentList->begin(); 
        while(iter != paymentList->end()) //runs to end 
        {
            method = (*iter)->getMethod();
            *save << method << "\n";
            if(method == 1)
            {
                pCash->saveCashPayments(save);
            }
            else if(method == 2)
            {
                pCredit->saveCreditPayments(save);
            }
            else
            {
                pCheque->saveChequePayments(save);
            }
            iter++;
        }
        save->close();
        delete save;
    }
}
```

It works if I save one type of payment, but as soon as I have two or more payments in the list I get a violation reading location error. I'm guessing it has to do with the type casts being wrong or something? In case I'm wrong here is an example of my save function that runs based on the method variable.

```
void Cash::saveCashPayments(std::ofstream* save)
{
*save << this->cashTendered << "\n";
*save << this->getId() << "\n";
*save << this->getAmount() << "\n";
*save << this->getOrderId() << "\n";
*save << this->getMethod() << "\n";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can't store objects with different sizes inside a vector.

Comment: `std::ofstream* save = new std::ofstream();` GAH! No! Say `std::ofstream save("payments.txt");` instead.

Comment: @Ian: He's not. He's storing pointers.

Comment: @IanMedeiros: That's a nice "polymorphic vector" there: it stores pointers, which are all the same size (*and* type).

Comment: Oh, thats true! Didn't realized it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is completely wrong approach.

A better approach would be runtime polymorphism. Declare a virtual function called `Save` in  base class and define it in each derived class.

For example, if `Payment` is the base class, then do this:

```
class Payment
{
   public:
     virtual void Save(std::ostream & out) = 0;
};
```

Then implement `Save` in all derived classes.

```
class Cheque : public Payment
{
   public:
     virtual void Save(std::ostream & out) 
     {
            //implement it
     }
};

class Cash : public Payment
{
   public:
     virtual void Save(std::ostream & out) 
     {
            //implement it
     }
};

class Credit : public Payment
{
   public:
     virtual void Save(std::ostream & out) 
     {
            //implement it
     }
};
```

And then call `Save` using pointer of `Payment*` type.

```
void savePayment(ListOfPayments & payments)
{
    std::ofstream file("Payments.txt");
    for(ListOfPayments::iterator it = payments.begin(); it != payments.end(); ++it)
    {
         it->Save(file);
    }
}
```

No need to pass `payment` by *pointer*; also don't use `new std::ofstream`.

Read about Runtime Polymorphism in C++.

Comment: Hi, thats great i can see that working but for some reason I cant seem to implement it :/
when i call savePayment what am I supposed to be passing to it? 
savePayment(&paymentList)? because that currently gives me a red line.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @MikeTarrant: If you can't implement it, then take your time, read and learn about runtime polymorphism; know how it works, and how it doesn't; Once you understand it, and its power, you will solve your problem very elegantly.

Comment: @MikeTarrant: No. Just write `savePayment(paymentList)`. It seems you also need to read about pass by reference, and pass by value, pass by pointers. etc.

Comment: @Mike:  'savePayment(paymentList)'.

Comment: well iv sorted that. was looking at it a bit wrong. where on the solution it has...
it->Save(file); typing it-> doesnt show a function to choose.
Confused.com :(

Comment: @MikeTarrant: That is the problem with intellisense, and it might not be that powerful.

Comment: ah right i got it all working now. before I try it out I just wanted to get a bit of knowledge.. When it calls this save function, how does it know whether to use the cash,cheque or credit function as the it->save is pointing to the payment fucntion.

Comment: @MikeTarrant: That requires lots of explanation. That is why advised you to read about runtime polymorphism. Get a good book on C++. and read it.